# read from file and split the information based on a character c#

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

i am reading information from a text file and i want to go through the text file row by row and in each row i want to split each sentence from the other based on a character(eg. ',') and i want to save the data in an array but when i print it i am getting just the last result.

```
     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StringArray = null;
        //to get the browsed file and get sure it is not curropted
        try 
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                {
                    string data;
                    while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                    StringArray = data.Split(',');
                    }
                }
                   for (int i = 0; i < StringArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = StringArray[i];
                    }
                FilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = (string)File.ReadAllText(FilePath.Text);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {

            MessageBox.Show("there is an error" + ex+ "in the file please try again");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error:

Above you define:

```
string StringArray = null;
```

Then later you use it as:

```
StringArray = information.ToString().Split(SplitCommas);
```

Split returns string[] not string. you need to change the declaration at the top to..

```
string[] StringArray;
```

The error: "cannot implicitly convert a type string[] to string". should give you the hint that you are trying to store a string array into a string.

Comment: i did what you said the problem is when i print it i am just getting the last result and i am printing it in a for loop

Comment: When you say "print it" do you mean set textbox1.Text?? If so you are setting textbox1 many many times to new values, but overwriting the previous value you wrote. What you are probably looking to do is append the text ( like textbox1.text += StringArray[i], although a stringbuilder would be more applicable). I'd assume this won't be the last bug you find in this code though, so I recommend adding in some breakpoints and powering through it for a bit longer.

Comment: The problem he is encountering is because he is replacing his array inside the loop until he reads the end of the file so the only value in the string array are the last line read.  I would recommend a List<string> for the string array and then AddRange data.Split(",") so that the for loop gets all the split strings.

Comment: Yeah, there other errors in there too, like at the very end overwriting all of the form1 changes with a brand new File read. I assume he is a bit more of a neophyte here thoguh and he'll figure those out after some debugging. In fact most of the source could be rewritten to          string[][] output = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FILENAME).Replace("\r","").Split('\n').ToList().Select(a=>a.Split(',')).ToArray();   but what use would that be to helping him learn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define StringArray as a `String[]`

```
string[] StringArray = null;
```

You might be better off using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) instead of the for loop

```
StringArray = data.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd line you a declaring String array as a string, you should declare it as an array:

```
string [] StringArray = null;
```